# How to fix the unusual webpage behaviour - multiple btn active of "portfolio"

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm facing a problem in fixing up this unusual web page behavior. I have included Github page link. On removing nav tag the problem gets solved. But I need the nav tag.

I tried deleting the nav element from dev console and found the nav tag is effecting the below section "workshop_intro".

Here is the Github page link: 
https://sarang13579.github.io/expt/

Github code:
https://github.com/sarang13579/expt

```
<section class="workshop_intro">
<div class="container py-2">
  <h1 class="py-4"><strong>Gallery</strong></h1>
  <p>Cut and Engraved products range</p>

  <h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
  <div id="myBtnContainer">
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('wood')"> Wood Cutting and Engraving</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('stone')"> Stone Engraving</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('glass')"> Glass Engraving</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('others')"> Others Cutting and Engraving</button>
  </div>
```

I expect the portfolio section "workshop_intro" button to highlight one at a time without removing nav tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be due to presence of another HTML element with the "active" class. the query `document.getElementsByClassName("active");` is returning the li element from the nav bar

`<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link px-5" href="index.html">Home</a>
</li>`

To select the button more accurately you can use `document.querySelector(".btn.active");`

Below is the working code

```js
filterSelection("all") // Execute the function and show all columns
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1); 
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.querySelector(".btn.active");
 current.classList.remove("active");
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 8px -16px;
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column (if you want) */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none; /* Hide columns by default */
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Content */
.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Add a dark background color to the active button */
.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
   color: white;
}



body, html {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row{
 margin: 0;
}



/*HEADER*/

/* Header Section */
.intro {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 88vh;
 padding: 0;
 background: url(../images/tooplate_middle_alt2.png) top center no-repeat;
 background-color: #f6f6f6;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
}

.intro .fa {
 font-size: 94px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 color: #fff;
}
.intro h3 {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.intro p {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 22px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 line-height: 28px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.intro .btn-custom {
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
header .intro-text {
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding: 25px 25px;
}

.intro-text i{
 color: white;
 /*size: 20px;*/
}

.intro-text a{
 cursor: pointer;
 
 /*transition: all 0.9s;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.9s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;*/
}

/*GRID - SECTION*/

.grid-list{
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;

}

.r1 {
 margin-bottom: 25px; 
}

.r2{
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.round img {
 position: relative;
 width: 165px;
 height: 165px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.more{
 cursor: pointer;
}

.updates{
 padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
 background: #f6f6f6;
}

.update{
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.partners{
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0;

}


.thumbnail{
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
 margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}



/*FOOTER*/

footer {
 background: #333;
 width: 100%;
 /*padding: 30px 0 20px;*/

}

footer .container{
 padding: 30px 0 20px;
}

footer .social ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

footer p {
 color: #666;
 font-size: 15px;

}






.company{
 padding-top: 25px;
}

.title {
 color: grey;
}

.round2 img {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 65%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 10px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}


.fakeimg {
 background-color: #aaa;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
}

.blg_img img {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 height:auto;
 object-fit: cover
}

.blg_img2 img {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 height:200px;
 object-fit: cover
}

.span4 img {
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.span4 .img-left {
 float: left;

}
.span4 .img-right {
 float: right;
}

.contact{
 padding: 50px 0;
}

.our_company{
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.products{

}

.blog{
 margin: 25px 0;
}


/*Laser technology*/

.pimg img{
 width: 100%;
}

.laser_page h1{
 color: #007BFF;
}

.product-detail ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: none;
    margin: 8px 15px;
    
}

.product-detail ul li a {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #6d7a83;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.laser_tech .carousel-caption {
  bottom: auto;
  top: -10px;
  right: -125px;
}

.laser_tech .carousel h5{
 color: #007bff;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 20px;

}

.laser_tech .carousel-indicators li{
 background-color: #007bff;
}

.laser_tech .carousel-control-next-icon{
 background-color: #000;
}

.laser_tech .carousel-control-prev-icon{
 background-color: #000;
}


.laser_page .card{
 padding: 15px 0;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

.laser_page .card-img-top {
 height: 145px;
}

.laser_page .card-body .btn-primary{
 bottom: 0;
}






.CO2 h2{
 color: #007BFF;
}


.CO2 img, .fiber img, .marking img{
 max-height: 260px;
 max-width: 330px;
}


.fiber h2{
 color: #007BFF;
}

.sz{
 font-size: 12px;
}

.marking h2{
 color: #007BFF;
}

/*Laser workshop*/
.workshop_intro h1{
 color: #007BFF;
}

.laser_work .card{
 padding: 15px 0;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

.laser_work .card-img-top {
 height: 180px;
}

.laser_work .card-body .btn-primary{
 bottom: 0;


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/portfolio.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>


<body class="d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: 100vh">

  <main class="flex-fill">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/tooplate_logo.png"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link px-5" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link px-5" href="about.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link px-5" href="blog.html">Blogs</a>
          </li>
        <!-- <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-5" href="products.html">Products</a>
        </li> -->

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle px-5" href="products.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Products
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <!-- <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> -->
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="products.html">Products Page</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="laser_technology.html">Laser Technology</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="instruments.html">Instruments</a>
            
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="laser_workshop.html">Laser Job Shop</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="service.html">Service</a>
          </div>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link px-5" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>





  <!-- Laser Technology -->

  <!-- <section class="laser_tech">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="py-4">Laser Job Shop</h1>

      <div class="row py-4">

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="round">
            <div class="fakeimg">Fake Image</div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="round">
            <div class="fakeimg">Fake Image</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section> -->


  <!-- Laser Workshop -->

  

  <section class="workshop_intro">
    <div class="container py-2">
      <h1 class="py-4"><strong>Gallery</strong></h1>
      <p>Cut and Engraved products range</p>


      

      
      <h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
      <div id="myBtnContainer">
        <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('wood')"> Wood Cutting and Engraving</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('stone')"> Stone Engraving</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('glass')"> Glass Engraving</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('others')"> Others Cutting and Engraving</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column wood">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Mountains</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column wood">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/lights.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Lights</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column wood">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/nature.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Forest</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column stone">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/cars1.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Retro</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column stone">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/cars2.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Fast</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column stone">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/cars3.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Classic</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column glass">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/people1.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Girl</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column glass">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/people2.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Man</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column glass">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/people3.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Woman</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column others">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/people1.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Girl</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column others">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/people2.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Man</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column others">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="images/people3.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
            <h4>Woman</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- END GRID -->
      </div>




      


    </div>
  </section>








</main>

<!-- FOOTER -->


<footer>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="social">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <p>&copy; example</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, and sorry for my stupid mistake. Your solution is right on spot. Thanks again

Comment: @Sarang, you are welcome. I'm glad I could help, and no mistakes are stupid, we all learn from our mistakes.

rely on Chrome DevTools or any other similar tools to debug the issue. They are very helpful.